# observable collection filters WPF and different way to filters the dat

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am developing a WPF application where i am following MVVM model, i am trying to filter the observable collection but this method is not returning any values public void UpdatePopList() , is this code written in correct way or i need some modification and also are there any different way to filter the data ?

```
private string selectmu;
    public string Selectmu
    {
        get
        {
            return selectmu;
        }
        set
        {
            selectmu = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Selectmu");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CREntity> _CRmappings2 = new ObservableCollection<CREntity>();

    public List<CREntity> CRPopentities
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // Obeservable collection property for access
    public ObservableCollection<CREntity> CRmappings2
    {
        get { return _CRmappings2; }
        set
        {
            _CRmappings2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CRmappings2");
        }
    }

    public void UpdatePopList()
    {
        CRPopentities = CRPopentities.Where(p => p.MU_Identifier == selectmu).ToList();
    }
}
```

This the UI binding code

```
                            <md:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
                                    <md:PackIcon Kind="DotsHorizontal" Margin="4 0 4 0" Width="24" Height="24"
                Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=md:PopupBox}, Path=Foreground}" />
                                </md:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Opened">
                                    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.popSW, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" CommandParameter="{Binding MU_Identifier}" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <!--<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=CRDataGrid, Path= SelectedItem.MU_Identifier}" />-->
                            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CRPopentities, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Software Versions" Binding="{Binding Path=SW_Version}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </md:PopupBox>
```

Comment: I think in UI you binded 'CRmappings2' but you are filtering the entity class. Should it be the ObservableCollection that you should filter.

Comment: @Eldho Yes you were right, i changed it to filter the observable collection to like this CRPopentities = CRmappings2.Where(p => p.MU_Identifier == selectmu).ToList(); --- as per the query it should multiple records right ? its only returning single record, is this because i am using ToList() ?

Comment: I think its doesn't contain multiple records with `MU_Identifier `. ToList() is correct. You can debug it.

Comment: @Eldho I debugged the code and it returned 3 records but on UI it was showing nothing. I think i am missing on the binding part.

Comment: @Eldho this is my binding code 
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CRPopentities, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Software Versions" Binding="{Binding Path=SW_Version}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>

Comment: Add to your question its difficult to read from here

Comment: @Eldho Thank you, I added the code to the question

Comment: I think you have binded the wrong property in UI. it should be `CRmappings2`.

I still have confusion which is your data source. Please mention your data source. From your binding it says like it is `CRPopentities` but i haven't seen anywhere you fill the data. If you fill the data it should work.

Comment: @Eldho CRmappings2 is the observable collection which is the datasource and the CRPopentities is the filtered list which is derived from CRmappings2 , i changed the mapping to CRmappings2 but it still didn't work.

Comment: Update your UI binding to CRmapping2

Comment: @Eldho i updated but it doesn't work, I am lost in these bindings :( , as per the code CRmappings2 is the observable collection and CRPopentities is the list collection, i am filtering the CRmappings2 and passing the result to CRPopentities, so logically my grid should bind to CRPopentities and also raisepropertychanged event should trigger on CRPopentities... errgh how tough this is

Comment: @Eldho this worked after i set the datacontext of popup box, DataContext="{Binding TESTModel,Source={StaticResource Locator}}" . Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that u query your Data and store them in a different List.

```
    public void UpdatePopList()
    {
        CRPopentities = CRPopentities.Where(p => p.MU_Identifier == selectmu).ToList();
        CRmappings2.Clear();
        foreach (var item in CRPopentities)
        {
            CRmappings2.Add(item);
        }

    }
```

Generally i think you should try to name your variables clearer.

Maybe this helps you
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/C-Sharp-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions/

Comment: Thank you for the input, but this didn't work because CRPopentities is empty list and i got the right solution from @Eldho, i had to just change it like this --- CRPopentities = CRmappings2.Where(p => p.MU_Identifier == selectmu).ToList();